# Why hwclock is neither UTC nor local?

Tags: time, timezone

```
$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Fri 2015-01-30 11:04:51 CET       correct UTC+1
  Universal time: Fri 2015-01-30 10:04:51 UTC       correct UTC
        Timezone: Europe/Budapest (CET, +0100)      correct
     NTP enabled: n/a
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no                                ? UTC then ?
      DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
                  Sun 2014-10-26 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2014-10-26 02:00:00 CET
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
                  Sun 2015-03-29 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2015-03-29 03:00:00 CEST
$ sudo hwclock
Fri Jan 30 12:05:09 2015  -0.406771 seconds         ??????? UTC+2 ??????
$ date
Fri Jan 30 11:08:30 CET 2015                        correct
```

The documentation of `hwclock` says that it always displays local time, no matter whether RTC is set according to local or universal time.

What could cause hwclock to display UTC+2 as the local time?

I originally thought that hwclock "believes" the RTC to be set according to UTC, hence it displays +1, since I am in central Europe, but the RTC is actually in local time (+1 already) hence it disaplays +1+1=+2. But `timedatectl` above "says" that RTC is not local. So what is going on?

update:

```
$ sudo hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.20.1
Using /dev interface to clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/01/30 11:38:38
Hw clock time : 2015/01/30 11:38:38 = 1422617918 seconds since 1969
Fri Jan 30 12:38:38 2015  -0.516275 seconds
```

So it "thinks" RTC is UTC but is actually local. Hence `timedatectl` is the culprit?

Comment: Just for the record, on my system, `timedatectl` and `date` behave as you describe, but `hwclock` displays local time, like it should. What does `sudo hwclock --debug` give you?

Comment: Your hardware clock is actually an hour ahead. (I'm in the same time zone as you.) UTC time should have been 10:38, not 11:38. So you are correct to say that is not consistent with `timedatectl`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your BIOS and set the BIOS clock to UTC and set the time correctly there!
2. In Windows, set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal"` to `dword:00000001`
3. Still in Windows, go to Control Panel, Add/remove Sftware, Change windowssettings, add Windows Time server.
4. In Ubuntu, `sudo nano /etc/default/rcS` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> `UTC=` if the value is `no`, change to `yes`
5. Still In Ubuntu [follow the official instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html) to install `ntp`
6. `sudo reboot`

### Problem gone!

**Why Windows?**  Well, if your settings are off, I infer that you *must be dual-booting and windows messing things up!*  **Szívesen! ;-)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 8 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: @EdiD: BIOS questions are off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu.  Try downloading the BIOS manual for your machine and look there...